# К каким типам тестов отнести тесты потокобезопасности метода

Tags: юнит-тесты, test-driven-development

Допустим есть такой метод:

```
bool IsValid()
{
    var argument = StaticClass.CurrentArgument;
    return argument > 0;
}
```

Для него есть юнит тесты, которые проверяют, что логика работает верно. Но не покрыт кейс, когда метод дергают из разных потоков. Так вот, тест, проверяющий потокобезопасность - это ближе к юнит тесту или к интеграционному? Также если есть общеизвестный другой тип тестов, подходящий под этот дело, тоже было бы неплохо узнать.

Условимся, что потокобезопасность проверяется легко, допустим достигаться она будет путем добавления блокировки прямо в этом методе.

На мое разумение ближе к интеграционному, ибо цель теста проверить не бизнес логику (ее проверка будет уже следствием), а именно использование кода в боевых условиях.

Отвечая на этот вопрос, наверное, важно понимать насколько значима потокобезопасность для бизнеса, т.е. насколько это бизнес логика. И похоже, что не столь значима. Ведь блокировка может быть, например, перед вызовом метода `IsValid()` и все будет также исправно работать. Но сдругой стороны, если мы четко указываем в контракте метода, что метод потокобезопасный (например в названии метода или документации), наверное следует тестировать это здесь же, как логическую состовляющую метода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Деление тестов на модульные и интеграционные происходит по принципу используются ли внешние зависимости или нет и насколько крупную единицу вы тестируете. Внешние зависимости -- это базы данных, сторонние веб-сервисы и т.д.

Если внешние зависимости отсутствуют, это означает, что а) настройка теста тривиальна, б) тест работает очень быстро.

Если присутствуют внешние зависимости, это всегда означает, что вы тестируете более крупные компоненты кода (т.е. интеграцию разных компонент между собой).

Т.о. тесты, проверяющие потокобезопасность, относятся к юнит-тестам. (А если вы вдруг захотите тестировать потокобезопасность с использованием внешних зависимостей, подумайте трижды и откажитесь от этого.)

P.S.

> проверить не бизнес логику, а именно использование кода в боевых
>   условиях.

А бизнес-логика в боевых условиях не используется что ли? :)

Comment: Используется. Но например при интеграционном тестировании акцент на проверку бизнес логики конкретных методов куда меньше, чем при юнит-тестировании. Отсюда и родился вопрос. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Serg046 да, но в интеграционных тестах бизнес-логика по-прежнему проверяется. Просто не на уровне методов/классов, а целых компонент или систем. Привязывать определение тестов к бизнес-логике некорректно. Не за что!